# Translate this code from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do you convert the following C# code to VB.NET?

```
private static readonly ICollection<string>
    _skipHeaders = new[]
        {
            "Connection",
            "Keep-Alive",
            "Accept",
            "Host",
            "User-Agent",
            "Content-Length",
            "Content-Type",
            "Accept-Encoding",
            "Authorization",
            "Referer",
            ProxyMethodHeader,
            ProxyAuthorizationHeader,
            ProxyAcceptHeader,
            ProxyAgentHeader,
            ProxyQueryHeader
        };
```

Comment: A reference code-conversion service is at [http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) (both C# to VB.NET and C# to VB.NET).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will work for vb9

```
Private Shared _skipHeaders as ICollection(Of String) = New String() { _
  "Connection", _
  "Keep-Alive", _ 
  ...  }
```

Comment: Thanks, the line continuation characters were the missing link.  I got the same output as the first answer from the online code translators.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Shared ReadOnly _skipHeaders As ICollection(Of String) = New () 
{"Connection", "Keep-Alive", "Accept", "Host", "User-Agent", "Content-Length", "Content-Type", "Accept-Encoding", "Authorization", "Referer", ProxyMethodHeader, ProxyAuthorizationHeader, ProxyAcceptHeader, ProxyAgentHeader, ProxyQueryHeader}
```

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted JaredPar's answer because it's correct. For future reference, there's a great conversion tool at http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/.

Comment: The code conversion at developerfusion.com is usually good, in this case, it did not include the line continuation characters.

Comment: well - thats true - but only because it did it on one line, so the continuation arent necessary.